# Использование регулярных выражений для разделения строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Есть строка, обозначающая собой название и номер версии, например `1.1_test12`, `1.5.2_dev1` или `2.10`.
Мне надо разделить название на две строки, если в нем присутствует конструкция `_word`, хочу использовать `String.split()` в Java, но никак не могу разобраться с тем, какое regex надо использовать тут.

Comment: так что во всех этих случаях должно получиться?

Comment: если `1.1_test12` то номер версии `1.1` и номер сборки `12`, или просто номер версии `2.10` если не указана сборка

Comment: `String[] res = "1.5.2_dev1".split("(?=_[A-Za-z])");` можно попробовать использовать позитивный просмотр вперед на наличие символа подчеркивания и латинской буквы после него. Результатом будет: res[0] - `1.5.2` и res[1] - `_dev1`

Comment: а есть возможность в одном выражении еще отсеять `_dev` чтобы осталось только `1.5.2` и `1`?

Comment: @kojisky `String[] res = "1.5.2_dev1".split("_[a-zA-Z]+");` так? Или нужно что бы первым была версия, вторым была среда и третьим сборка?

Comment: @ipatev_nn спасибо, все работает как я и хотел

Comment: @ipatev_nn а каким способом можно разделить на три составляющих, не теряя `_dev`?

Comment: @kojisky добавил ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] res = "1.5.2_dev1".split("(?=_[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\\d)");
/*Результат:
res[0]: 1.5.2
res[1]: _dev
res[2]: 1
*/
```

`(?=_[a-zA-Z])` - ищем в строке место где идет знак `_` и после него буква латинского алфавита.
`|` - или
`(?<=[a-zA-Z])` - смотрим назад на любую букву латинского алфавита
`(?=\\d)` - и после идет цифра

---

```
String[] res = "1.5.2_dev1".split("_[a-zA-Z]+")
/*Результат:
res[0]: 1.5.2
res[1]: 1
*/
```

`_` - знак нижнего подчеркивания
`[a-zA-Z]+` - одна и более латинская буква